# NSDictionary is nil when I decode with NSKeyedUnarchiver even when passing valid data object

Tags: ios, core-data, nskeyedunarchiver

I am storing NSDictionary object using NSKeyedArchiver with the below code under core data.

```
            NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
            NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
            [archiver encodeObject:dict forKey:@"voterExtraInfo"];
            [archiver finishEncoding];
            [voter setValue:data forKey:@"extraInfo"];
```

When retrieve the same dictionary with key @"voterExtraInfo", NSDictionary is showing nil. 
My retrieval code is

```
    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:voter.extraInfo];
    NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
    NSDictionary *extraData= [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"voterExtraInfo"];
    [unarchiver finishDecoding];
```

Please suggest. Here is the dict I am storing.

```
{
     "ethnicity": "Hispanic",
     "voter_score": "45",
     "ipsum": "foo bar"
}
```

Comment: check voter.extraInfo is nil.

Comment: what is the class of `voter`?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. check if voter.extraInfo object is having correct data.

Comment: voter.extraInfo is returning some data in kilobytes. It is not nil. Class of voter is Voter.

Comment: @Shoaib, How to check whether it is having correct data or not.

Comment: What is the attribute type of `extraInfo` in the Core Data model editor?